# Defining the height of the jqPlot horizontal bars and the distance between them

Tags: javascript, html, jqplot

is there a way to define the height of the horizontal bars and the distance between them. I am searching for a possibility to put as many horizontal bars in a view as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
                    seriesDefaults: {
...
                            rendererOptions: {
...
                                barPadding: 1,
                                barMargin: 10,
                                barWidth: 20,
...
                            } 
                        },
```